# C++ sum series factorial

Tags: c++, factorial

We are suppose to get a sum series but I am running into a problem.

1/n + 2/n-1 + 3/n-2 ...n/1 is the sum she wants

My for loop is not right and I can't figure out why 
The answer is suppose to be 8.70 but I get 27.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{  

int n=5;
float sum=0;

    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        for(int j =n; j>0; j--){
            sum += i/j;

        }
    }
   cout<<"Sum : "<<sum;}
```

Comment: When `i` is `1`, `j` is `n`. But the first term of the series is `1/n - 1`. Also, `1/5` is `0` in integer arithmetic!

Comment: add a `cout` in the inner loop to make sure `i` and `j` are what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are using two loops to compute the sum while the series sum can be computed by a single loop. That should be a red flag.
2. Also, you are using integer division. That's going to give you wrong results.

Use:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{  
   int n=5;
   float sum=0;

   for(int i=1; i <= n; i++)
   {
      sum += i*1.0f/(n - i + 1);
   }

   cout<<"Sum : "<<sum;
}
```

Comment: hey, I was trying to do it in 2 for loops because I am reading from an array. double sum;
 int j =1;

 for(int i =0; i<=size; i++){
     sum +=nums[i]*1.0/(size-j+1);
     j++;
 }

Comment: Hey, @isabella, you could also check my answer below for more explanation on how to use `i` and `j` in parallel instead of the nested fashion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have two for loops first, it can be done by one loop only

```
 int main(){

    float n=5; //need to declare as float otherwise the statement(i/n-1) will be 0 if declared as int
    float sum=0;


        for(int i=1; i<=n-1; i++){ //the loop should go to n-1 only otherwise denominator becomes 0 which makes it Infinity


                sum += (i/(n-i));

        }
        cout<<"Sum : "<<sum;
    }
}
```

i hope this answers your questions with doubts as well @isabella

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with some template metaprogramming.  Then the sum will have zero runtime cost.

```
#include <iostream>

template < int n, int i = n >
struct sum
{
  static double value()
  {
    return i*1.0f/(n - i + 1) + sum<n, i-1>::value();
  }
};

template < int n >
struct sum < n, 0 >
{
  static double value() { return 0; }
};

int main()
{  
   std::cout << "Sum : " << sum<5>::value() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using two for loops does not serve your purpose because the inner loop will be repeated as many times as the outer loop specifies. in your case, you will get:

```
   1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5  
 + 2/1 + 2/2 + 2/3 + 2/4 + 2/5  
 + 3/1 + 3/2 + 3/3 + 3/4 + 3/5  
 + 4/1 + 4/2 + 4/3 + 4/4 + 4/5  
 + 5/1 + 5/2 + 5/3 + 5/4 + 5/5  
 + 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 5/5
```

However, you need `i` and `j` to work in parallel as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;

    float sum = 0;

    cout << "\n Enter n: ";
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 1, j = n; i <= n; ++i, --j)
    {
        sum += (float)i/j;
    }

    cout << "\n\n Sum is " << sum;
}
```

Also note that `int/int` will result in an `int`. for example: `9/2` is `4`. Hence, you need to convert one of the operands to `float` to get a `float` result.

Answer (score 0):

**There is different way to solve this problem you have seen so far. As you are using C++ language, here you can take the concept of using 'fixed' digit after the decimal number is printing.**

> Here the code of your desire question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{  
   int n=5;
   double sum=0,j = 1.00000;

   for(int i=n; i >= 1; i--)
   {
      sum += i*j/(n - i + 1);
   }

   cout<<" Sum : " << setprecision(1) << fixed << sum << endl;
}
```